# What's the difference between %TMP% and %TEMP% in Vista environment variables?

Tags: windows, variables, temp

On my computer, the environment variables %TMP% and %TEMP% both point to the same location.

Are those for backward compatibility issues only, or is there a real difference?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It is for compatibility. It goes all the way back to DOS. Since there were no standards, some DOS (and Win 3.x) applications would look for the %TMP% environment variable and others would look for %TEMP%. You were best off if you set both of them in the AUTOEXEC.BAT file.

Windows NT set both of them automatically just to make sure all of the apps continued to work OK. %TEMP% is the standard now, but %TMP% lives on.

EDIT: Looks like Richard already mentioned the DOS aspect in a comment.

Comment: According to https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20150417-00/?p=44213, `%TMP%` is the default in Windows, rather than `%TEMP%`.

Answer (score 15):

To complete the other answers:

[Environment variable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable#Examples_of_DOS_environment_variables)

> in **[MS-DOS 5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_x86_DOS_operating_systems)** (1991-1994) **%TEMP% sometimes pointed to C:\DOS** so removing all files in %TEMP% would cause great problems to say the least.

[image: http://www.operating-system.org/betriebssystem/bsgfx/microsoft/msdos500-scr-01.png]

Comment: MS-DOS Shell screenshot--That brings back memories. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I think only for compatibility, as I could see in Windows starting from NT 4.0 both variables were targeted to the same location in `%WinDir%\Temp\`

Also I never saw using `%TMP%`, every time it was talking about `%TEMP%`.

Comment: +1 compatibility. Back to the days of MS-DOS when some apps used TMP and others used TEMP. (Could even be back from Unix vs. CPM style.)

Comment: Unix tools from `Git` pack uses `%TMP%`.

Answer (score 3):

[Raymond Chen](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20150417-00/?p=44213) talks about the historical use of `TMP` and `TEMP`, and says this specifically about Windows:

> For whatever reason, the original authors of the [Get­Temp­File­Name](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-gettempfilenamea) function chose to look for `TMP` before looking for `TEMP`.

The rest of the article is worth a read in explaining the historical use of both in DOS.  It sounds like DOS preferred `TEMP` semi-officially, rather than `TMP`, but third-party programmers were free to use what they liked, particularly given the lack of the standard API functions that Windows has.