# Does %TEMP% and %TMP% referes different locations for computers running Terminal Service

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, temporary-files, group-policy

A windows 2000 computer running Terminal Service creates a temporary folder for each terminal session, and it appends the hexadecimal value to the temporary folder name depicted by the environment variable %TEMP%.

Reference

[Terminal Services Temporary Folder Configuration Is Stored in Multiple Registry Locations](https://www.betaarchive.com/wiki/index.php?title=Microsoft_KB_Archive/243555) (formerly http://support.microsoft.com/kb/243555)

[Temporary Folders](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732258%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)

[Use separate temporary folders for each session](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc759190%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)

My Question is does %TMP% also behaves in the similar manner as %TEMP% or it refers to a different location (the parent directory of %TEMP%).

**Note** I know people would tend to say that this question is related to SU but I am trying to use the Environment Variables in my program as a temporary store. So that makes it a programming question. Problem is that as TEMP folder is deleted once the user logs of this creates issues causes services to crash. Ok I understand this is not a good solution to use temporary store but we just looking for a short term solution until we come up with something better.

Answer (score 0):

**[TorgoGUy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/44318/torgoguy)** Have answered a question similar to this:

**[What's the difference between %TMP% and %TEMP% in Vista environment variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/581966/whats-the-difference-between-tmp-and-temp-in-vista-environment-variables)**

> **It is for compatibility**. It goes all the way back to DOS. Since there
>   were no standards, some DOS (and Win 3.x) applications would look for
>   the **%TMP%** environment variable and others would look for **%TEMP%**. You
>   were best off if you set both of them in the AUTOEXEC.BAT file.
>
> Windows NT set both of them automatically just to make sure all of the
>   apps continued to work OK. **%TEMP%** is the standard now, but **%TMP%** lives
>   on.

And Yes both variables **%TMP%** & **%TEMP%** point to the same location `%WinDir%\Temp\`

Hope this helps.

Comment: Actually I did see the link but the scenario is different here. If you see the links included, you will see that on a Windows Server, using Terminal Service, the TEMP location is appended with a session value something like c:\Users\<User Name>\AppData\Local\Temp\<Session Number>, which is something not desirable. I have checked that this only affects %TEMP% and not %TMP%. Also all the msdn links mentions about %TEMP%. I would like to know, if it is well documented that session value is not suffixed with %TMP%.